# Pandas returns string value from dataframe aggregate max() of count() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count, max

I am learning Pandas and struggling with the simpler stuff.

Ultimately I want my code to return only 'oranges' because is has the most occurrences of a value in the column COLOR.

My index is currently the x column.

```
X    FRUIT   COLOR
10  apples  green
10  apples  red
10  oranges green
10  oranges orange
10  oranges yellow
10  bananas yellow
10  bananas green
```

I always seem to end up returning a key value pair or just the .count() number and can't seem to pull just the FRUIT column value from the aggregate results.

Here's one of my code samples trying to solve it - I've tried many but this is the latest one that's not working:

```
df['COUNT'] = df.groupby(['FRUIT'])['FRUIT'].transform('SIZE')
copy_df = df
max = copy_df.loc[df['SIZE'] == copy_df['SIZE'].max()]
print(max)
```

This returns "AttributeError:  'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'SIZE'"  - I've had other tries with better results but I can tell I'm not getting anywhere fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need change `SIZE` to `size` in `transform`:

```
df['SIZE'] = df.groupby(['FRUIT'])['FRUIT'].transform('size')

max1 = df.loc[df['SIZE'] == df['SIZE'].max()]
print(max1)
    X    FRUIT   COLOR  SIZE
2  10  oranges   green     3
3  10  oranges  orange     3
4  10  oranges  yellow     3
```

If need top value of column `FRUIT` use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and then first value of index by `index[0]`, because output is sorted:

```
print (df.FRUIT.value_counts())
oranges    3
apples     2
bananas    2
Name: FRUIT, dtype: int64

val  = df.FRUIT.value_counts().index[0]
print (val)
oranges
```

Another solution with aggreagate [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html) for check index value of max value of `Series`:

```
print (df.groupby('FRUIT')['FRUIT'].size())
FRUIT
apples     2
bananas    2
oranges    3
dtype: int64

val = df.groupby('FRUIT')['FRUIT'].size().idxmax()
print (val)
oranges
```